# Strange behaviour of C code(fgets function)

Tags: c, cc

In my C program, `fgets` is not reading any data. Please see the below code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
        char string[50];
        int marks,i,n, limit;
        printf("Enter Limit : \n");
        scanf("%d", &limit);
        FILE *fptr; fptr=(fopen("string.txt","w"));
        if(fptr==NULL){
                printf("Error!");
                return 0;
        }
        printf("Enter a string : \n");
        fgets(string, sizeof(string), stdin);
        fwrite(string, 1, sizeof(string), fptr);
        fclose(fptr);
        return 0;
}
```

After I entering limit, the program shows "Enter a string" and just exits(Before entering any data). If I remove the  `scanf("%d", &limit);` statement it works fine. Also if add a `getchar();` statement above `fgets` it will work fine. Does anyone know the reason behind this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because of your use of `scanf` earlier in the code. When you enter the number as input, you press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key to mark the end of the input and that adds a newline in the input buffer. What `scanf` does is read the number, but leave the newline (enter key) in the input buffer. Then when you call `fgets` it sees this lone newline and reads it.

A very simple solution to this is to tell `scanf` to skip trailing whitespace by adding a single space after the format code:

```
scanf("%d ", &limit);
/*       ^         */
/*       |         */
/* Note space here */
```

---

If the above solution doesn't work, then you can read characters until you get a newline:

```
int c;
while ((c = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF && c != '\n')
    ;
```

Also, in Mac OSX there is the [`fpurge`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man3/fflush.3.html) function which can be used to clear unread data from an input stream:

```
fpurge(stdin);
```

**Note:** The`fpurge` function is ***not*** portable.

On Linux and Windows you can use `fflush` to perform the same thing `fpurge` does, but note that it's extensions in the libraries for Linux and Windows that allows it. Calling `fflush` on an input stream is, according to the C specification, undefined behavior. See e.g. [the Linux manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fflush) or the [Windows reference page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yky46tz.aspx).

Comment: I changed the code like this. scanf("%d ", &limit); But now output is like this: 1. Enter the limit 2. 3(Comment : Entered Limit and press Enter ket) 3. sswew(Comment : I had to enter something here again and press enter again) 4. Enter a string (Comment : Before entering anything program exits)

Comment: I don't know why this is not working for me. When giving an extra space after `%d` I have to press an extra character and that makes program to terminate.

Comment: Joachim Could you please check this? I am using Mac OS X 10.8 and CC Compiler. Above solution is not working for me.

Comment: @jsq Updated my answer with an alternate solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `sscanf` and enter number, you hit "Enter"... number is processed by `sscanf`, but "Enter" is handled by `fgets`

Answer (score 0):

This is because `fgets` reads the newline character `\n` left behind by the previous `scanf`. One possible way to eat up this `\n` add a `getchar` after `scanf`.

```
    getchar();
    printf("Enter a string : \n");
    fgets(string, sizeof(string), stdin);
```